# How to express y from $\dfrac{y-2x}{y}=1$?

Tags: problem-solving

I need to express y from $\dfrac{y-2x}{y}=1$, I mean get the $y=...$ equation. But I'm getting 0 instead of y:

$\dfrac{y-2x}{y}=1$

$y=y-2x$

$y-y=-2x$

$0=-2x$

Comment: Your steps are correct. From your last equation we can see that $x$ has to be 0. Substituting back into the original equation you get $\frac{y}{y} = 1$, which is true for all $y \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$.

Comment: @ViktorGlombik Actually, the reason I do this is that I need to make a plot y(x). What should I do? Or it is impossible?

Comment: This equation simply does not determine $y$ as function of $x$. Think about giving it individual values of $x$. Giving it $x=0$, it returns ALL $y \neq 0$. Given any other $x$ you don't even get a $y$ out. But a function has to assign a (unique) $y$ to each $x$. So $y$ certain isn't a function $y(x)$.

Comment: Regarding the plot: You would [essentially get the $y$-axis](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+(y+-+2x)%2Fy+%3D+1).

Comment: It depends upon how the question was asked. If you are asked to graph $\left\{(x,y)\,|\,\frac{y-2x}{y}=1\right\}$ then that is the $y$-axis minus the origin. But the equation does not define $y$ as a function of $x$.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales, what do You mean by "y-axis *minus the origin*"?

Comment: I mean $\left\{(0,y)\,|\,y\ne0\right\}$.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales, seems, I'm too stupid to understand this. This https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+(y+-+2x)%2Fy+%3D+1 plot corresponds the equation?

Comment: You only have to understand that if $x=0$ and $y\ne0$ then $\frac{y-2x}{y}=\frac{y}{y}=1$ and that there can be no other kind of solution to the equation. We know that $y$ must not be $0$ and that if both $x\ne0$ and $y\ne0$ that leads to a contradiction of a non-zero number equal to $0$. So the only solutions are $\left\{(0,y)\,|\,y\ne0\right\}$.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales, ok